# What is the parent class of NSMutable array?

Tags: objective-c

What is the parent class of NSMutable array? Is it NSArray?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Look at the documentation...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It says "Inherits from  NSArray : NSObject"

Answer (score 2):

`NSArray`, then up to `NSObject`.

(it's detailed in [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the interface)